# Extracting Names from Excel Based on DateTime Input and Shift Times in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, office-interop

I'm working on a C# project where I need to retrieve names from an Excel sheet based on a given DateTime input. The Excel sheet has a table with shift times for each day of the week (Monday to Sunday) and corresponding names for the Early (7:00 AM to 1:30 PM) and Late (1:30 PM to 9:00 PM) shifts. The names are located in cells B4 to H4 for the Early shift and B5 to H5 for the Late shift.

|  | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Time |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Early 7-13 | name | name | name | name | name | name | name |
| Late 13-21 | name | name | name | name | name | name | name |

I'm using C# with Microsoft Excel to handle the data. The Excel sheet is structured with two rows for each day: one for the shift times and one for the corresponding names. The time values are in 24-hour format, and there is no special formatting applied to the cells.

My current approach involves iterating through the rows and columns of the used range in the worksheet. For each row representing a day of the week, I check if the DateTime input falls within the Early or Late shift timeframe and matches the day of the week. If the conditions are met, I try to retrieve the name from the corresponding cell.

Here's a snippet of my existing code:

```
public static string GetName(Worksheet worksheet, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            string Name = "";

            DateTime weekStartDate = dateTime.Date.AddDays(-(int)dateTime.DayOfWeek);

            var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
            var rows = usedRange.Rows;
            int rowCount = rows.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                var row = (Range)rows[i];
                if (row.Row == 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var dayOfWeekCell = (Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
                var dayOfWeekText = dayOfWeekCell.Text;
                if (!Enum.TryParse(dayOfWeekText, out DayOfWeek dayOfWeek))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var columnCount = usedRange.Columns.Count;
                for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++)
                {
                    var column = (Range)usedRange.Columns[j];
                    var columnHeader = column.Cells[1, 1].Text;
                    if (string.Equals(columnHeader, dayOfWeekText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        var shiftTypeCell = (Range)row.Cells[2, j];
                        string currentShiftType = shiftTypeCell.Text;
                        if (dateTime.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0) && dateTime.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0) && string.Equals(currentShiftType, "Früh", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Name = (row.Cells[4, j] as Range).Value;
                        }
                        else if (dateTime.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0) && dateTime.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0) && string.Equals(currentShiftType, "Spät", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Name = (row.Cells[5, j] as Range).Value;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

            return Name;
        }
```

which im calling like this:

```
        string Person = Helpers.GetName((Worksheet)shiftsWorksheet, zeitpunkt);
```

When I call the GetName function with a DateTime input of '04.03.2023 14:30', I expect the function to return the name from cell G5 (Late shift on Saturday).

I have searched for solutions to my problem before posting this question. However, I haven't been able to find a solution that dynamically switches between shifts based on the DateTime input.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no G5 and not saturday in you example data?

Comment: It's just an example to visualize the structure of the sheet, i'm going to edit the question, it goes on to sunday.

Comment: "doesnt work" is the worst explanation of your problem, Please clarify that!

Comment: It's supposed to return the string in the shift sheet, for the current row's datetime in the data sheet, but its always null.

Comment: You have changed the code in your question completely.....   May I advice you to keep on debugging before asking a question, so you will have a FIXED problem, and not a moving problem ?

Comment: Yes i did, as i figured out some misconceptions on my side. I'm not sure how to debug this at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code

1. this skips line 1 of you Excel doc.

```
   var row = (Range)rows[i];
                if (row.Row == 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

2. No clue what is (supposed to ) happen here.  Cell[1,1] is value from the first column, but you are at line 2, the result will be "Time".  Your code hits the `continue`, because this is not a weekday.  This will happen for all next lines in your sheet.

```
var dayOfWeekCell = (Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
                var dayOfWeekText = dayOfWeekCell.Text;
                if (!Enum.TryParse(dayOfWeekText, out DayOfWeek dayOfWeek))
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

3. I was planning on looking at the rest of the code, but there's no need (see 2.)

**EDIT**

This seems to work, and look easier than your approach:

```cs
        public static string GetName(Worksheet worksheet, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            
            string Name = "";

            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("NL");
            int dayOfWeek = (int)dateTime.DayOfWeek;  // 0=Sunday; 1=Monday; .....; 6=Saturday
            int schedule = dateTime.Hour >= 13 ? 4 : 3;

            int column = 1 + (dayOfWeek==0 ? 7 : dayOfWeek);
            int row = schedule;

            Name = worksheet.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value;

            return Name;
        }
```

With my schedule:
[image]

Four sample outputs of this code:

```
At 4-3-2023 15:27:37, the schedule point to: name12
At 5-3-2023 15:27:37, the schedule point to: name14
At 6-3-2023 15:27:37, the schedule point to: name2
At 7-3-2023 15:27:37, the schedule point to: name4
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, i see what you mean, i've removed that. Objective is simply to Return Cell Values based on the shift scheme off of a datetime value when columns B-H are Monday to Sunday, and row 3 is early and row 4 is late shift (or whatever row pair), with the shift determining off of the Datetime.Time, like i've included. I feel like there is a way more simple way of achieving this. One more thing i just noticed that the Weekdays are not written in english, but also after fixing that, returning null only.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: That's really clean. It's the solution but how would you go with 13:30 as the shift switch as i cant use new TimeSpan(13, 30, 0) with int?

Comment: Currently the line `int schedule = dateTime.Hour >= 13 ? 4 : 3;` is determining if you need line #4 or line #3 of the excel-sheet.  You can make this line more complex and use: `(dt.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds >= (13 * 3600 + 30 * 60) ? 4 : 3)` to check for 13:30.